# How do LSTM units incorporated spatial or sequential information?

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, sequential

As I understand it, LSTM units are linked in sequence and each unit has an output, and each LSTM unit passes an output to the next LSTM unit in the chain.

However, don't you put your entire input in every LSTM unit? I don't see how this chain reflects the structure of the data in which the sequential order matters.

Can someone explain where I go wrong? I'm particularly interested in the version of lstm implemented in keras but every answer is very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, LSTM units are all parallel.

The sequence exists only in the data itself, when you separate a dimension to be what they call the **time steps**. Data passed to an LSTM is shaped as (Batch Size, Time Steps, Data Size).

The sequence occurs in "time steps", but all units work in parallel.

Even an LSTM with only one unit will still work in a sequence with the time steps.

What happens to LSTMs is that they've got a "state". It's an internal matrix that is like it's memory. In each sequence step, there are "gates" (other matrices) that decide, based on the step input, if that step will change the state and how much. There are also "forget gates", that decide if the old state will kept or forgotten.

---

In keras, you can have the attribute `return_sequences` set to true or false.

If true, the result will carry the results of each time step.
If false, only the final result will be output.

In both cases, units will be just a "size" of the result. (Pretty much as the units in a Dense layer, or the filters in a Convolutional layer, they're more power, more features, but not more steps).

The output with `return_sequences=False` will have only the units as size: `(Batch Size, Units)`
The output with `return_sequences=True` will keep the time steps: `(Batch Size, Time Steps, Units)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! So if I have a very large dataset of sequential data and I cut it up into little pieces of let's say length 10. Then if I feed this sequences of length 10 it to my single unit LSTM the length of 10 becomes a time step of 10, and in the first phase my unit will process the first element in the sequence and in the second the second, until the last phase in which it analyses the 10th element of my sequence. Then if `return_sequences=False` it will return only the output of the last time step and if `return_sequences=True` it will return outputs of all timesteps?

Comment: Does this mean that if I want to predict the previous element I'd have to feed the sequence in reverse order?

Comment: This large dataset, does it have one single huge sequence that you divide? Or does it have a lot of different sequences?

Comment: There is a difference between "cutting" and "shaping". If you shape it as (N_examples, steps, 10), you will have many steps, but each step will process 10 elements at once (as if the were not a sequence in these 10 elements). If you shape it as (N_examples, 10, n), it will have 10 steps. --- For "cutting" a sequence (creating many batches to send one at a time), you have to change `stateful` to `True`. Then you can actually pass the sequence parts one at a time (this is a way to deal with lack of processing capability or memory).

Comment: And yes, to predict the previous element, the best idea is to use a reverse sequence. For that you have the `go_backwards` parameter in the LSTM layer.